# How to fix weight/widget growth imbalance?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

This problem has happened to me multiple times in multiple codes, and not once have I figured out the way to fix it. The widgets at the column 0 row 0 are growing and placed differently than others. When I grab the end of the window to extend it and make it grow its gap is increased between it and other widgets.

I have included a picture for you to see what happens:

[image: Dice 1 widget seperated from other widets]

This is the code that shows the problem:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root=Tk()

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

#Grows the items in the gui
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)


ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Dice 1:").grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Dice 2:").grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Total:").grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

root.mainloop()
```

The problem seems to be coming from either this statement:

```
mainframe.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
```

or from this statement

```
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: what behavior do you want? Do you want `mainframe` to stick to the upper left corner of the window when the window is resized, or do you want it to fill the window? Or, do you want it to be centered so that any extra space goes around the edges equally? What about the labels, what should they do? Do you want them to stay at the top, or be centered within `mainframe`?

Comment: I want it to fill the window and as for the labels they should be an equal distance away from each other.

Comment: "fit the window" is too vague. You want them to stretch horizontally and vertically when there's extra space? Stretching text vertically can't be done. or do you really mean you want them to stay in the upper-left corner and all blank space should go to the right and bottom of the window?

Comment: I want the labels to evenly spread out in the column and be in an equal distant away from each other. Extra space is fine as long as it is does not interfere with the equivalent distance of each of the labels. The right side is fine the way it is as it can be filled later.

Comment: So, extra vertical space goes below the labels? what about mainframe? How should it behave when the window resizes? Specifics are important; there is no single answer to "how to fix weight/widget growth imbalance?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first widget behaves differently because you configured the first row of `mainframe` differently. If you want all rows behave the same way then configure them the same way. Either remove this

```
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

or add this

```
mainframe.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to remove the `weight` attribute for row 0 (zero) in `mainframe`, and instead give the weight to row 3. The reason being, you don't want any extra vertical space being allocated to the labels, and a positive `weight` attribute causes some of the extra space to be given to that row or column.

By giving a positive weight to the empty row after the labels is that all of the empty vertical space will appear below the labels.

```
mainframe = Frame(root, background="pink")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
```

It's hard to say if that's the actual correct solution to your problem because that depends a bit on how you expect `mainframe` itself to behave. Should it shrink to fit the labels? Should it grow to fit the main window?